# JsonMappingException when run as junit at Eclipse Amazon lambda function

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

In Eclipse, i created a new Amazon lambda function to a `dynamodb` event. I didn't implement anything, the code is as the Amazon wizard creates the project.

When i run the test as junit, it returns:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting setter definitions for property "eventName": com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Record#setEventName(1 params) vs com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Record#setEventName(1 params)

I try to solve this with `@JsonIgnore`, but i get the same result.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I pass the junit test modifying the class of the object input from DynamodbEvent to Object at the test method:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandlerTest {

//private static DynamodbEvent input;
private static Object input;

@BeforeClass
public static void createInput() throws IOException {
    //input = TestUtils.parse("dynamodb-update-event.json", DynamodbEvent.class);
    input = TestUtils.parse("dynamodb-update-event.json", Object.class);
}
```

And at the lambda function I change the class to the input object too:

```
public class LambdaFunctionHandler implements RequestHandler<Object, Object> {

@Override
public Object handleRequest(Object input, Context context) {
```

Comment: Did you ever get a better answer to this?  I'm running into the exact same problem.  In my code, parsing the JSON works just fine.  However, when running it as a JUnit test I get the parsing exception.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find a better answer to this.

Comment: Please have a look to [Joost Den Boer workaround](https://www.diversit.eu/post/2017/11/01/deserializing-aws-dynamo-event.html) which solved problem for me.